# Text is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for 'ul'

Tags: html, razor

I was wondering if I could have someone on here look over the following segment of code 
that I have and provide me suggestions about how to restructure it properly.

Currently, I'm getting the following warning error for it:
"Validation (HTML5): Text is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element 'ul'."

Any ideas about how I can remove that warning? When I insert an
"li" tag in there, it tells me that I can't overlap "li" tags. So I know that solution won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

```
<ul class="menuList">
     @if (Model.PurchaseForm.WorkFlowStep != "e")
     { 
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "PurchaseApprovalForm_Edit", "Forms", new { id = @Model.PurchaseForm.PurchaseApprovalForm_PK }, new { @class = "menuButton" })</li>
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delegate", "DelegateForm", "Forms", new { id = @Model.PurchaseForm.PurchaseApprovalForm_PK, formType = "Purchase" }, new { @class = "menuButton" })</li>             
         if (User.IsInRole("Pur_Requestor"))
         {
           <li><span id="undo" class="menuButton" style="cursor:pointer">Cancel Form</span></li> 
             {
                 Html.Telerik().Window()
                          .Name("Window")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "display:none;" })
                          .Title("Confirm")
                          .Draggable(false)
                          .Resizable(resizing => resizing
                              .Enabled(false)
                              .MinHeight(250)
                              .MinWidth(200)
                              .MaxHeight(500)
                              .MaxWidth(500)
                          )
                          .Modal(true)
                          .Buttons(b => b.Maximize().Close())
                          .Content(@<text>
                               @using (Html.BeginForm("PurchaseApprovalForm_Cancel", "forms", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "confirmform" }))
                               {
                                   <li>
                                   <input type=hidden id="formid" name="formid" value="@Model.PurchaseForm.PurchaseApprovalForm_PK"  />
                                   <label>Reason :</label> @Html.TextArea("reason", new { cols = 70, rows = 2 })
                                   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
                                   </li>
                               }
                               </text>)
                               .Width(600)
                               .Height(300)
                               .Render();
             }
             {
                Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
                   .OnDocumentReady(@<text>
                        var windowElement = $('#Window');
                        var undoButton = $('#undo');
                        undoButton
                            .bind('click', function(e) {
                                windowElement.data('tWindow').open();
                                undoButton.hide();
                            })
                            .toggle(!windowElement.is(':visible'));
                        windowElement.bind('close', function() {
                            undoButton.show();
                        });
                    </text>);
             }
         }
     }
      </ul>
```

Comment: Try to validate the *generated* HTML code.  Not whatever this code is.

Comment: This is more about razor and visual studio...

Answer (score 1):

If the view/result works then you can ignore the visual studio warnings, you get these when you put `@if(..) { ... }` and `@Html..`. stuff in your razor view.

Comment: Alright, I will go ahead and ignore it for now. Thanks. I just wasn't too sure if that error would turn out to be a vital problem for me over time.